# Converting string to struct tm in C

Tags: c, string, date

I am trying to convert a string to a struct tm.  below is my code....i am getting this error when I compile but I am not sure what/how to change the line around so that it works.

v245-2% g++ prog1.c
prog1.c: In function `char* calcage(char**, char**)':
prog1.c:143: error: cannot convert`char*' to `tm*' in assignment

```
char* calcage(char **individual, char **age)
  {
    time_t time_raw_format;
    struct tm * time_struct;
    char *birthday = (char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    struct tm * birthparse;
    struct tm * birth_struct;

    char buf [100];

    time ( &time_raw_format );
    time_struct = localtime ( &time_raw_format );

    strftime (buf,100,"It is: %m/%d/%Y.",time_struct);
    puts (buf);

    printf("person: %s\n", *individual);

    birthday = strrchr(*individual, ',');
    birthday++;

    printf("Birthday:  %s\n", birthday);

   birthparse = strptime(birthday, "%D", birth_struct);
 }
```

Comment: There's a few things wrong here... `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1 on all C implementations. You shouldn't be casting the return value of `malloc` in C. `birth_struct` is an uninitialised pointer (points to nowhere) so your program will likely crash when it reaches the last line of your function. Your function doesn't return a value.

Comment: The very title of this question pasted as a search criteria with the [c] tag will likely yield the results you're looking for if you just look.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issues I raised in the comment, the reason you are getting the error is because [`strptime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/functions/strptime.html) returns `char *`, not `struct tm *`, so the assignment to `birthparse` is not valid.

`birth_struct` should be declared as a normal struct, not a pointer to a struct, and you should give the address of `birth_struct` to `strptime`, e.g.

```
struct tm birth_struct;

// ...

strptime(birthday, "%D", &birth_struct);
```

If the parse was unsuccessful, `NULL` is returned from `strptime`, otherwise the address of the last character parsed is returned.

Comment: I see what you mean.  It worked.  Now, how do i print it to the screen?  would it be printf("%a value \n", &birth_struct);?